# need to protect global variable in tornado?

Tags: python-2.7, tornado

Tornado is running in single thread.
At one time point,is there only one function running?
So I don't have to get a lock to protect the variables?
Even the those functions are asynchronous?

Comment: Please add your code and related info. See the tutorial for questioning http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tornado functions run uninterrupted until a "yield" expression (if the function is a coroutine) or the function returns. So the answer is no, you don't generally need to protect global variables with locks in a Tornado application.

If you require that only one coroutine can use a shared global variable, Python's standard threading.Lock is the wrong way to achieve this. (Indeed, using a threading.Lock in a single-threaded Tornado application will lead to a deadlock.) Instead, using a tornado.locks.Lock to coordinate coroutines' access. But this is an advanced use-case that you near-certainly don't need to worry about.

For background, read Glyph's famous "Unyielding" article:

https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2014/02/unyielding.html

It's about Twisted, but applies to asynchronous coroutine- and callback-based applications generally.

Comment: The first two sentences seem to be contradictory in async, non-blocking stack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to protect global variables if two or more functions that use the variable are scheduled in the IOLoop. E.g. while async handling many http requests.

You can use [toro's Lock](https://toro.readthedocs.org/en/stable/classes.html#lock) In tornado 4.2+ you can use [tornado.locks](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/locks.html#tornado.locks.Lock), since toro as been merged to Tornado.

The case:

- there is function that modifies `test_var` and call a dependent function, that takes a bit longer
- there is function that clears `test_var`

Example:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado import gen
import time

test_var = 'test'

@gen.coroutine
def sleep():
    yield gen.Task(IOLoop.instance().add_timeout, time.time() + 0.1)

@gen.coroutine
def depend_on_test_var():
    yield sleep()
    print('depend_on_test %s' % test_var)

@gen.coroutine
def set_test_var():
    global test_var
    test_var = 'set'
    yield depend_on_test_var()

@gen.coroutine
def clear_test_var():
    global test_var
    test_var = 'clear'


@gen.coroutine
def main():
    print('main start %s' % test_var)
    yield [
        set_test_var(),
        clear_test_var()
    ]

IOLoop.instance().run_sync(main)
```

It runs one function at a time. Since the `yield` of non-blocking function (asynchttpclient, async sleep and so on) means **do something else till it's done, the ioloop takes next scheduled function** - this is bit a oversimplified.

Of course this is only example, and can be changed with separate `yields`:

```
@gen.coroutine
def main():
    print('main start %s' % test_var)
    yield set_test_var()
    yield clear_test_var()
```

Comment: you are right , and sorry i didn't describe my question clear.